# Printing Stabilizer State of a circuit using Cirq

Tags: programming, cirq, stabilizer-state

How to print the stabilizers for a given circuit using Cirq (just like in Qiskit)?

For example, if I have the following cluster state and make a circuit using Cirq. I give the circuit as input, and I should have the output as: {+XZII, +ZXZI, +IZXZ, +IIZX}

[image: 4 node cluster state]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, though there might be some better UX on top of it that I'm not aware of.

```
a,b,c,d = cirq.LineQubit.range(4)

circuit = cirq.Circuit(cirq.H.on_each([a,b,c,d]),
                       cirq.CZ(a,b),
                       cirq.CZ(b,c),
                       cirq.CZ(c,d)
                       )
t = cirq.CliffordTableau(4)
state = cirq.CliffordTableauSimulationState(t, qubits=[a,b,c,d])
for op in circuit.all_operations():
  cirq.act_on(op, state)

print(t)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It is really working with any given circuit